# What does the behavior that volatile solve called?

Tags: java, multithreading

If I have multiple threads accessing the same global variable, each thread can cache the value of this variable, and access this cached copy from now on. I can use `volatile` to prevent this from happening, for example:

```
volatile int i = 123;
```

My question is: what does this behavior called (the behavior that each thread creates its own "copy" of the variable)?

Comment: I believe you can call it compiler optimization :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call it code optimisation, cpu optimisation, compiler optimisation.  Using volatile also provides happens-before and happens-after guarantees.

Note: this optimisation can be done by the `javac`, the `JIT` or the CPU.

Comment: But what is the benefit of such optimization, I mean if the compiler sees that I am writing to this variable in one thread, and then reading from this variable in another thread, then why do this "unhelpful" optimization?

Comment: @paul it is very hard for the compiler to see that this is happening, and it is very expensive to not do this optimisation. It can be 10x slower which is a high price to pay. The compiler has to see that you are not using some other thread safe operation, say in another class.

Answer (score 1):

Esentially, volatile is used to indicate that a variable's value will be modified by different threads.

Declaring a volatile Java variable means:

The value of this variable will never be cached thread-locally: all reads and writes will go straight to "main memory";

Access to the variable acts as though it is enclosed in a synchronized block, synchronized on itself.

Comment: What does it mean when a thread "can cache" a variable? Can you describe how it works please